# System App Permissions

Tags: applications, root-access, system, unrooting

I have an application that needs root permissions to run.  No biggie, all of my personal devices are rooted, so I am very comfortable with the process. The problem is that this application is to be used on company owned devices issued to certain employees and I don't want them to be able to uninstall the application nor do I want them having root access to the device.

I was thinking that the following process would accomplish my goals:

1. Root the device
2. Install my app as a system app
3. Launch the application and grant su rights to it
4. Unroot the device

Since it would be a system app, and the device wouldn't be rooted, users would be prevented from removing the app.  What I am unsure of is whether or not that application would retain its root privileges once the device is unrooted?

Any feedback or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You cannot install your app as system app, as you need the same signing key that was used to sign the ROM in question. If device becomes unrooted, it automatically loses root.

Comment: What about applications like Titanium Backup Pro or /system/app mover that convert user apps to system apps?  Using one of those applications it is possible to make a user app a system app.

Comment: Even if this worked, what would prevent someone from rooting the device again and removing the app?

Comment: Technically, nothing.  But since the app I'm looking to install is for monitoring and managing the device remotely, I'd be able to tell if they had.

Comment: How? From the statement above - "I don't want them to be able to uninstall the application nor do I want them having root access to the device." thing is, they *can* uninstall it any time.. there's nothing to stop them from doing so, even with adb and usb cable, the employees could be tech savvy about it without you knowing it..

Comment: Actually, it'd be pretty simple to tell....if the app stopped reporting, and examination of the device revealed they had uninstalled it, I fire them for tampering with my equipment.  If through the monitoring I find SuperUser.apk installed, I know they've re-rooted the device and I fire them for tampering with my equipment.

Comment: Hmmm... only thing I can think of is to create a custom ROM, that is dependent on what device is in question, if they are all of the same, the job will be much easier, if not, you've got problems. And simply modify the AOSP source to prevent package manager from uninstalling, that is, you need to hack up a quick one line solution in the bowels of it and bundle it with superuser and your app, that is hidden from view.. other than that, if talking about without a roll-your-own approach, you're pretty much out of luck!

Comment: @t0mm13b Actually, that TiBu approach should work: root → install TiBu → convert app to system app (i.e. it gets installed to `/system/apps`) → uninstall TiBu → unroot. Done. That app would have access up to "signatureOrSystem" protection levels then. But giving it *root* access is something different (and probably not even needed here).

Answer (score 1):

As [ProNetGuru](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/54842/pronetguru) already pointed out, [Titanium Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) could indeed be used for that:

1. root
2. install TiBu
3. convert app to system app (i.e. it gets installed to `/system/apps`
4. uninstall TiBu
5. unroot.

Done. That app would have access up to "signatureOrSystem" protection levels then (if specified so in its Manifest).

Giving it root access is something different – but probably not even needed here.

Comment: For an app to have `signatureOrSystem` level would have to have `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` in the manifest **and** signed with the same signing key as the ROM... tbh, have never tried it.. for a normal app that has normal manifest as in not having the above tag does not necessarily imply that it has that signatureOrSystem protection level, even if it was installed as a "system app".

Comment: Oh. I might have gotten that part wrong (so it's only protection-level "system" then; but what, please, is the difference between "signature" and "signatureOrSystem" then? There's no separate "protectionlevel system"). But please correct me: I thought it's not possible to "give an app root access" and then unroot the device while still having that sticking. So this is the closest one can get to, given the circumstances.

Comment: `signatureOrSystem` protection level means it can do `rm -rf /` without needing root! And do things that a normal root can do (uid of 0) - that is ultimate. There's many different `sharedUserId` levels, such as for example: `android.uid.phone`, if that `android:sharedUserId` tag has the above example, it means an app can do anything relating to the telephony layer and nothing else. Its a far more finer grain of access control behind the scenes for system level apps and also to minimize breach and malice. All TiBu does, it remounts system r/w and moves the app there, nothing else.

Comment: And, if those system apps, i.e. baked into the ROM, have their digital signature removed, it will refuse to run, so you can see why there is another degree of protection levels lower below the normal android manifest permissions.

Comment: Also to add more thought to this, suppose the OP went off and built their own ROM with said app having that tag in the manifest, installed into system and signed with newly created ROM signature - happy days. Then, if the OP decides to update the said app via play store and distribute from there, it will fail to upgrade because the signing keys mismatches, and the only way to get the upgrade to work would mean... yes, uninstall the system app, and install from play store! *Phew* hard explaining it all. :)

Comment: Yuck. So it seems the entire question is rather XY. What are we talking about? What is really needed? Why does it need to be "a system app with root access"? Maybe I rather delete my answer straight away?

Comment: Its rather more like OP setting question as XY and yes, OP did say "Launch the application and grant su rights to it" and unroot it which is putting OP into a no-win situation. The answer below is concise and simple and is the correct answer despite OP not accepting anything else...

Comment: OK, so I'll leave at this point. OP should test if it works for him, and then accept whichever of the two answers proved correct.

Comment: its murky!!! :D :) _o/

Comment: I very much appreciate all of the information and insight provided by everyone.  I will be testing this in the next week or so and will accept an answer and let everyone know how it works out.

Comment: @t0mm13b you're a little green. Go check your facts (and please don't take offense). You're just flat out wrong about a lot of what you've said in these comments.  Let me know if you have any questions.  System apps cannot do `rm -rf /`.  The system partition is read only.  You need to remount it r/w.  Further you do not need to have the same signature as system apps to be a system app.  `signatureOrSystem` on a permission has nothing to do with being a system app.  It is granted to apps in the system folder OR apps signed with the same key as the system itself.

Comment: @dcow while I can second most of your facts: isn't a "system app" exactly defined as being installed in the system folder? And couldn't they just do the remount themselves before executing `rm -rf`? But of course you're right saying "just having the permission in the Manifest is not enough": true, it must either be signed with the "system key" or at least installed as system app in the first place for that permission to be granted – but that's what step #3 of the answer does.